# Selenium invalid Xpath

Tags: python, list, api, selenium, datetime

I am using selenium to extract the half-hourly Wheather data from the table in https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/gb/london/EGLC/date/2018-01-1

Selenium cannot find the data in the given XPaths, for instance:
t = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/lib-display-unit/span[1]/span[1]")

Can someone help me identify where the bug is?

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/jdmba/chromedriver.exe')
Fromdate = '2018-01-1'

def Wheathertemp(date, driver):
    url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/gb/london/EGLC/date/"+date
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)

    t = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/lib-display-unit/span[1]/span[1]")
    temperature = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[2]/lib-display-unit/span[1]/span[1]")

    Wheather = []

    for i in range(1, len(temperature)):

        data = {'SP': str(i), 'timeObservation': t[i].text, 'temperature': temperature[i].text}
        Wheather.append(data)
    
    driver.quit()

    return Wheather


s = Wheathertemp(Fromdate, driver)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web site that you use does API call in order to get the data.

You can do that as well :-)

Use the code below.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.weather.com/v1/location/EGLC:9:GB/observations/historical.json?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&units=e&startDate=20180101&endDate=20180101')
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.json())
else:
    print(f'Oops. status code is: {r.status_code}')
```

In the browser do: *F12 -> Network -> XHR* and you will see the API call.

Comment: Do not send get request params in string, it could create problems, use `params` argument.

Comment: What are the possible problems? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @balderman, mostly encoding problems. In this particular case all values are ascii letters or digits, but it's not always the same. It's possible to construct url manually, but in that case you should apply url encoding on params ([`urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)).